# Is it possible to retrieve magnet link via transmission-remote?

Tags: bittorrent, transmission, command-line-tool, magnet-links

I'm running torrents on the home server, and I talk to home server via the `transmission-remote` utility. I'd like to retrieve the magnet link for one of my torrents, however this seems to be impossible, as the `transmission-remote -t[torrent-id] -i` doesn't give me the link, and the manual also says nothing. Is there any way to get a magnet link?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

May have been patched since the question was asked, but running

```
transmission-remote -l -t 13 -i | grep magnet
```

worked for me, got the magnet link for torrent number 13.

If you want only the link, you can `sed` away the title:

```
transmission-remote -l -t 13 -i | grep magnet | sed -e "s/^ *Magnet: //"
```

You may need to add a parameter `--auth <username>:<password>` for authentication.

Comment: In my version of transmission it doesn't work, but it's outdated, so I'll have to just believe you ) Thanks for the solution )

Comment: Running 0.8.5 (from gentoo net-p2p/bitcoind-0.8.5:0)

Comment: That works, but you don't need `-l`

Answer (score 8):

This worked for me :

```
transmission-remote -a magnet:?xt=urn...[magnet_link_here]...
```

Comment: To add a bunch of magnets from a.html page `Nokogiri::HTML(File.read("a.html")).css("a").map { |a| a["href"] }.sele
ct { |href| href.start_with?("magnet") }.each { |href| system("transmission-remote", "-a", href) }`